# new struct Linked-List in C, can be compiled but can't be executed

Tags: c

I want to store a new `struct data` in `LList`, the data type include a string, this code can be compiled, but when I execute it, it just return that the `list.exe has stopped working`.
what's wrong with my code?

```
typedef struct data{
    int vertex;
    char url[10];   
}Data;


typedef struct Node {
   Data         *v;
   struct Node *next; 
} Node;

Node *makeNode(Data n) {
   Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   assert(new_node != NULL);
   new_node->v->vertex = n.vertex;
   strcpy(new_node->v->url,n.url);
   new_node->next = NULL;
   return new_node;
}

int main(){
    Data n1;
    n1.vertex = 1;
    strcpy(n1.url,"a1");;
    Node *a = makeNode(n1);
}
```

Comment: `struct data` ... is there a case sensitivity issue here?

Comment: new_node->v is uninitialized

Comment: You should also allocate memory for the internal pointer of `Data` type structure inside `Node` structure.

Comment: `Data* v` so the access is right - only thing is you didn't allocate any memory that you start accessing it. Your weird spacing bettween  `Data               *v;` got me wrong.

Comment: @tim no, why would there be? Struct data is typedef-ed as Data.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)). Fix-my-code questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. You should give some [MCVE]

Comment: do a memset after malloc `memset(new_node,0,sizeof(*new_node));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's wrong with my code?

That's what:

```
  new_node->v->vertex = n.vertex;
```

particularly, you're dereferencing new_node->v like it's a legit address, while it's a random value.
Because of this line:

```
   Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

malloc() did allocated new_node for your, but it's a region of memory filled with random left-over bytes, so new_node->v is just a random binary sequence from you PC's RAM at this point.

When deferencing random number as an address, your program will request from the operation system a memory region your program should have no business with. Operation system will recognize it, issue a "segmentation fault" error(literary means - "you are out of your memory segment, buddy") and terminate your process.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is with

```
Data *v;
```

First you need to allocate some memory for it  ie immediately after `assert` put

```
new_node->v=malloc(sizeof *(new_node->v))
if(NULL==new_node->v)
    perror("Pgm failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or change the Node struct to include an instance of a Data struct rather than a pointer to it:

```
typedef struct Node {
   Data         v;         // <---    got rid of *
   struct Node *next; 
} Node;
```

Also, you could clean up your malloc a little bit, from:

```
Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

to

```
Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
```

There is no need to cast the return from malloc() and by using *new_node as the size, if the type for new_node ever changes, you won't have to change the malloc call.

Comment: won't help him, because he is still dereferencing 'next'

Comment: Hmmm, I'm missing the issue with 'next'.  He is correctly allocating memory for new_node, and even setting new_node->next to NULL.  It was memory for new_node->v that was not being allocated, which has nothing to do with using the next pointer.

Comment: @bedbad sorry, I don't get it. could u be more specific?

Comment: @LeshenZhu please check out my answer. After that ask me questions if you need more on how malloc/addresses/pointers in C work.